# Can anyone explain and trace the following multiple recursive C program?

Tags: c, recursion

I am trying to understand how recursion works. I seem to not understand how this multiple recursion works. Please help and thanks!

[Here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99YiA.png)

```
#include<stdio.h>
int R(int x);

int main()
{
    R(5);
    return 0;
}

int R(int x)
{
    if(x > 0){
        x--;
        R(x);
        R(x - 2);
        printf("%d ", x);
    }
}
```

Comment: **You** can trace it by stepping through line by line with a debugger.

Comment: Also, please note that using recursion like this is very bad practice. Instead of writing such needlessly complicated code, use loops.

Comment: I can only see it go line by line in debugger, I want to understand why it goes there. What is the logic behind it going there? (I purposely wrote the code like this to understand recursion. I couldn't understand multiple recursion in the likes of Mergesort)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`R(5)` calls `R(4)` which will display something and then `R(2)` which will also display something. After that `R(5)` displays `4`. Which is why you see a 4 at the end of the output.

R(4)display - **R(2)display** - 4

Before the 4 you have the display of `R(2)`. `R(2)` calls `R(1)` which displays somenthing and then `R(0)` which displays nothing. `R(2)` displays `1`. Which is why you have a 1 at the end, just before 4.

R(4)display - **R(1)display - R(0)display - 1** 4

And so on...

R(4)display - **R(1)display - 1** 4

R(4)display - **0 1** 4

You always process the R()display calls starting from the end (right side first).

As you can see recursivity will inverse the order of the numbers (4, the biggest number, is last). This is because you have the `printf` after the recursive calls to R.

Comment: I'm still unable to understand. What exactly happens? I can only see it go line by line in debugger, I want to understand why it goes there. What is the logic behind it going there?

Comment: what do you mean by "there"?

Comment: By 'there' I mean the next line of execution

Comment: When the execution point reaches a call to R() it will jump right back at the top of the function R. But this is another call to R, with different parameters (x is decremented). This is what recursivity means: R is calling itself so you will have one call to R inside another call to R etc.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the trace tree I made 
[image: trace tree]

R(5) means the call of R function for 5, and as you know the output of it will be 4. The numbers show in which order the functions are executed till the end. The ones that have a tick besides them will make outputs.

Comment: I'm still unable to understand. Could you please elaborate on the printing of the numbers?

Comment: as you see in the image R(5) starts executing,and in it's third line it will call R(x) (that is R(4) in this case). R(4) will call R(3). R(3) will call R(2) and R(2) will call R(1) and R(1) will call R(0). R(0) will be executed till the end of function and will be returned without an output.
We will be returned to R(1) and compiler will execute from the next line of R(0) and will call R(-1). It will be returned without any output as well. The next line in R(1) will print 0 and the function ends. We will be returned to R(2) and it will continue its execution. Just analyze the tree like that.